# Why a session exists before i start a session?

Tags: session

i am new to session. I am a little dizzy with session. Before, i thought we need to start a session first, and then we can use session to do what we want to do.

Today, i use eclipse to create a java web application. i have not do anything with session. But when i check the cookies, there is a JSESSIONID in the request cookies, its value is a string. The Domain, Path, and Expires are N/A.

Why a JSESSIONID exists already?

I know this question maybe stupid, but i an really confused with session.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Perhaps it might be worth rewriting it to use the word "session" a little more, that should clear things up :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have activated sessions then the JSESSIONID cookie will be created when you make a **new** request if you don't already have one, it will assign you an unique session ID.

You can disabled them using:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

Comment: Thanks. So the default setting of session is activated, right? The session does not exists anymore after i put what u write.

Comment: It depends which server you're running.

Comment: thanks so much. By the way, can we create multiple sessions? Such as, besides the session that already exists, i would like to create more sessions. How can we do this?